# Not sure how to sort an ArrayList based on parts of Objects in that ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a Sorts class that sorts (based on insertion sort, which was the assignment's direction) any ArrayList of any type passed through it, and uses insertion sort to sort the items in the list lexicographically:

```
public class Sorts
{
public static void sort(ArrayList objects)
{
    for (int i=1; i<objects.size(); i++)
    {
        Comparable key = (Comparable)objects.get(i);
        int position = i;

        while (position>0 && (((Comparable)objects.get(position)).compareTo(objects.get(position-1)) < 0))
        {
            objects.set(position, objects.get(position-1));
            position--;
        }   
        objects.set(position, key);
    }
}
}
```

In one of my other files, I use a method (that is called in main later) that sorts objects of type Owner, and we have to sort them by last name (if they are the same, then first name):

Directions: "Sort the list of owners by last name from A to Z. If more than one owner have the same last name, compare their first names. This method calls the sort method defined in the Sorts class."

What I thought first was to get the last name of each owner in a for loop, add it to a temporary ArrayList of type string, call Sorts.sort(), and then re-add it back into the ArrayList ownerList:

```
public void sortOwners() {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<ownerList.size(); i++)
        temp.add(((Owner)ownerList.get(i)).getLastName());
    Sorts.sort(temp);
    for (int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++)
        ownerList.get(i).setLastName(temp.get(i));
}
```

I guess this was the wrong way to approach it, as it is not sorting when I compile.

What I now think I should do is create two ArrayLists (one is firstName, one is LastName) and say that, in a for loop, that if (lastName is the same) then compare firstName, but I'm not sure if I would need two ArrayLists for that, as it seems needlessly complicated.

So what do you think?

Edit: I am adding a version of compareTo(Object other):

```
public int compareTo(Object other)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (lastName.compareTo(((Owner)other).getLastName()) < 0)
        result = -1;
    else if (lastName.compareTo(((Owner)other).getLastName()) > 0)
        result = 1;
    else if (lastName.equals(((Owner)other).getLastName()))
    {
        if (firstName.compareTo(((Owner)other).getFirstName()) < 0)
            result = -1;
        else if (firstName.compareTo(((Owner)other).getFirstName()) > 0)
            result = 1;
        else if (firstName.equals(((Owner)other).getFirstName()))
            result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the object should implement a `compareTo` method that follows the normal `Comparable` contract--search for sorting on multiple fields. You are correct that having two lists is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the `Owner` code to begin with, then change the code so that it implements `Comparable`.  Its `compareTo()` method performs the `lastName` / `firstName` test described in the assignment.  Your `sortOwners()` method will pass a `List<Owner>` directly to `Sorts.sort()`.

If you don't have control over `Owner`, then create a subclass of `Owner` that implements `Comparable`.  Call it `OwnerSortable` or the like.  It accepts a regular `Owner` object in its constructor and simply delegates all methods other than `compareTo()` to the wrapped object.  Its `compareTo()` will function as above. Your `sortOwners()` method will create a new `List<OwnerSortable>` out of the `Owner` list.  It can then pass this on to `Sorts.sort()`.

Comment: I already have Owner implement Comparable, and it does have a compareTo(Object other) method within it, and it does compare the lastName and firstName. So how would I apply that in sortOwners()?

Comment: Then you should be all set - just pass an `ArrayList<Owner>` to `Sorts.sort()`.

Comment: That's what I do, and I still get some things sorted, and some don't.

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `compareTo()`?  Maybe edit your original post and put it there.  Also, try using the `sort()` method on `java.util.Collections` and see if you get similar issues - this would just be to rule out bugs in `Sorts.sort()`.

Comment: Posted, and I'll check it out.

Comment: I just wrote a test program with your code.  I found that the array sorted properly with `Collections.sort()`, but not with `Sorts.sort()`.  It may be that your `compareTo()` is fine and that there is a bug in `Sorts.sort()`.  I will take a closer look.

Comment: I've confirmed it - there's a bug in `Sorts.sort()`.  I'm not sure what it is, but I can tell you that I re-implemented insertion sort using the Wikipedia article pseudocode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and got correct results.  And, as mentioned above, I got correct results with `Collections.sort()`.  Meanwhile, the current `Sorts.sort()` is failing. So summary is:  your `Owner` is fine, your `compareTo()` is fine, the bug is in `Sort.sort()`.  Take another look at it and study the algorithm in Wikipedia.  And if that leads you to the solution, be sure to accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, here's some hints:

1. Assuming that the aim is to implement a sort algorithm yourself, you will find that it is much easier (and more performant) to extract the list elements into an array, sort the array and then rebuild the list (or create a new one).
2. If that's not the aim, then look at the `Collections` class.
3. Implement a custom `Comparator`, or change the object class to implement `Comparable`.

Comment: I already have it implementing Comparable. And Owner.java does have a compareTo(Object other) method within it, and it does compare the lastName and firstName. So how would I apply that in sortOwners()?

Comment: If you've got a Comparator and/or your class implements Comparable, why are you extracting and sorting the owner names?  Did you read my second hint?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `ArrayList` of objects, ordinarily we would use the [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method to accomplish this task. Note the method signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

What's important here is that all the objects being sorted must implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which allows objects to be compared to another in numerical fashion. To clarify, a `Comparable` object has a method called `compareTo` with the following signature:

`int compareTo(T o)`

Now we're getting to the good part. When an object is `Comparable`, it can be compared numerically to another object. Let's look at a sample call.

```
String a = "bananas";
String b = "zebras";
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
```

The result will be -24. Semantically, since *zebras* is farther in the back of the dictionary compared to *bananas*, we say that *bananas* is comparatively *less* than zebras (not as far in the dictionary).

So the solution should be clear now. Use `compareTo` to compare your objects in such a way that they are sorted alphabetically. Since I've shown you how to compare strings, you should hopefully have a general idea of what needs to be written.

Once you have numerical comparisons, you would use the `Collections` class to sort your list. But since you have your own sorting ability, not having access to it is no great loss. You can still compare numerically, which was the goal all along! So this should make the necessary steps clearer, now that I have laid them out.